# Calling a group of methods from different classes in eclipse

Tags: methods

I'm new to programming in eclipce for android, and I'm a little lost, I'm trying to make an application with multiple screens, but with the same menus, the fact is that I have created several classes and each class several methods, now I want to include the same methods in each class, as I can encapsulate this group of methods into one and call them from different classes..

Here are the methods that are repeated in each class

```
public void lanzarConfig(View view) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Config.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void lanzarConsola(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Consola.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void lanzarAcercaDe(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, AcercaDe.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void lanzarSalir(View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Salir.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true; 
}

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.acercaDe:
            lanzarAcercaDe(null);
            break;

        case R.id.config:
            lanzarConfig(null);
            break;
        case R.id.consola:
            lanzarConsola(null);
            break;
        case R.id.salir:
            lanzarSalir(null);
            break;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

How do I to call them from other classes without having to copy the entire code..?

Answer (score 0):

Save these methods in new class `ClassName` and then use inheritance:

```
public class WhateverClass extends ClassName
```

Every instance of class WhateverClass can then use also methods of class ClassName.

Read more about inheritance [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).